# vertical lines changing length in different browsers, is this normal?

Tags: css

I've designed a 3 column site and I wanted to place a thin horizontal line between each column. I did this quite easily and got the exact height I wanted in Chrome, I then opened it in Firefox and the horizontal line was about 10px shorter, the same thing happened with IE9.
Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Is there anyway to fix this or do it better. This is the css I used, the html was just a div:

```
    #horizontal-dividing-line-news-arabnews {
    border-left: solid 0.1em #0099FF;
    height: 31.8em;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 7.3em;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: It could be due to user agent styles.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle demo also?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `em` ("ems") here as the unit for the size.

"Ems" are proportional to the current font-size and browsers might not all have the same default font-size so this is why the size vary.

You'll want to use `px` (pixels) for this.

Comment: ahh ok, I was told to use ems so it would adapt to different screen sizes, do you think it matters for a 1px horizontal line? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Border widths should normally be constant across any screen sizes, at least for very narrow ones. But using "ems" for font sizes is good, however %s should be used for your columns' sizes if you want them to adapt to the screen.